# real and imaginary part of a complex number

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, for-loop, complex-numbers

I have 2 pointers which points to two 20 member arrays. My arrays contains complex numbers. I want to make element by element division for that complex numbers that is why I need to separate numbers to real and imaginary parts. I tried the following code but it gives error.

```
    #include <complex>

    complex *a;
    complex *b;
    complex array1[20];
    complex array2[20];
    a = &array1;
    b = &array2;
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<=19;i++)
    {
    real_part_array1[i] = real(*a[i]);
    imag_part_array1[i] = imag(*a[i]);
    real_part_array2[i] = real(*b[i]);
    imag_part_array2[i] = imag(*b[i]); 
    }
```

First error I got was; I tried to write it as

```
    #include <complex.h>
```

the error message was "cannot open source file complex.h". Then i deleted h and error was gone. The second error I have is for real() and imag(). The error message is "identifier real is undefined".

For division I have to seperate them to real and imaginary parts but I dont know how to solve that problem. I hope you guys can help me.

Comment: You could just read the documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex . Also, what's with the pointers? What do you need them for?

Comment: this is a sample code that is why I defined them as 20. normally it is a piece of huge program and  there is 44100 values in pointer. Every other function use them as pointer so I am not allowed to change it to just array I have to use it as pointer. Before I asked my question I read documentation and tried solutions but did not work. I wanna know if there is a possibility that I have to write a header file with all that functions?

Comment: Does the documentation for `<complex>` say that it defines a global `real` function? If so, where does it say so? If not, why do you think your code should work?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/complex/creal I used this file and in their sample they used it like how I use, I tried crealf creal normal real. And from the documentation you linked I am not able to understand easily. Am I supposed to define all this functions in my cpp file I am working currently on? or are there any complex.h header file available to download. Thanks!

Comment: (To be clear, I didn't link to any documentation.) `<complex>` and `<complex.h>` are two different headers. You're linking to the C documentation for a function declared in `<complex.h>`, not to C++ documentation, even though your question is tagged C++. If your implementation doesn't have that, you generally can't just download it somewhere else, it needs to be made to work for your specific implementation. Since your implementation does not have `<complex.h>`, but does have `<complex>`, I'd say you should study the functionality provided by `<complex>` and use that.

Answer (score 2):

1. `complex` is not a type, it's a type template. You need to specify the type of the real and imaginary components as a template parameter, e.g. `complex<double>`.
2. The type template `complex` and the functions `real` and `imag` are in the `std` namespace.

   Regarding `complex<...>`, you can either write `std::complex<...>` or put `using std::complex; below your includes. (You could also write`using namespace std;` but that might be dangerous to get used to it.)

   Regarding `real` and `imag`, they can use ADL (**a**rgument **d**ependent **l**ookup: when their argument is in the `std` namespace, the function name is automatically looked up in `std` too), so you don't need to specify the namespace for these functions.
3. In the line `a = &array1;` (and the other one analogous), you point to the whole array `array1`, which is a pointer to array. What you probably want is either `&array[1]` or just `array1`, as arrays can be converted implicitly to the pointer to their first element.
4. In `*a[i]` you access the i-th element in the array `a` points to (`a` itself is not a pointer but the array subscript operator works on pointers as if they were arrays). Then you dereference that complex type, which is invalid. Simply drop the `*`.

You can see the final code [here](http://ideone.com/RDys1y).

Answer (score -1):

You probably want to use it like :

```
#include <complex>


int main()
{
    std::complex<float> *a;
    std::complex<float> *b;
    std::complex<float> array1[20];
    std::complex<float> array2[20];
    int real_part_array1[20];
    int real_part_array2[20];
    int imag_part_array1[20];
    int imag_part_array2[20];
    a = array1;
    b = array2;
    int i=0;
    for (i=0;i<=19;i++)
    {
    real_part_array1[i] = std::real(a[i]);
    imag_part_array1[i] = std::imag(a[i]);
    real_part_array2[i] = std::real(b[i]);
    imag_part_array2[i] = std::imag(b[i]); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

complex is not a type but a type template. Hence you may want to use something like complex< int > or complex< double >.

Also real and imag are in the std namespace, hence std::real and std::imag.

Now when you say a = &array1, array1 is already a pointer, you are assigning a pointer to a pointer to the LHS, which is a pointer, this is a type error

Comment: `std::complex<int>` has no meaning in standard C++. To quote the standard: "The effect of instantiating the template `complex` for any type other than `float`, `double`, or `long double` is unspecified."

Comment: Yes, sorry my bad. Totally missed that. Updated the answer.